# C++: Explicit DLL Loading: First-chance Exception on non "extern C" functions

Tags: exception, visual-c++, dll

I am having trouble importing my C++ functions. If I declare them as C functions I can successfully import them. When explicit loading, if any of the functions are missing the extern as C decoration I get a the following exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in cpp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

**DLL.h:**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int addC(int a, int b);
__declspec(dllimport) int addCpp(int a, int b);
```

**DLL.cpp:**

```
#include "DLL.h"
int addC(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
int addCpp(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "..DLL/DLL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 1;
    typedef int (*PFNaddC)(int,int);
    typedef int (*PFNaddCpp)(int,int);

    HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("../Debug/DLL.dll"));

    if (hDLL != NULL)
    {
        PFNaddC pfnAddC = (PFNaddC)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "addC");
        PFNaddCpp pfnAddCpp = (PFNaddCpp)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "addCpp");
        printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a,b);
        printf("pfnAddC: %d\n", pfnAddC(a,b));
        printf("pfnAddCpp: %d\n", pfnAddCpp(a,b)); //EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE

    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I import c++ functions for dynamic loading? I have found that the following code works with implicit loading by referencing the *.lib, but I would like to learn about dynamic loading.

Thank you to all in advance.

**Update:**
bindump /exports

```
1 00011109 ?addCpp@@YAHHH@Z = @ILT+260(?addCpp@@YAHHH@Z)
2 00011136 addC = @ILT+305(_addC)
```

**Solution**:

1. Create a conversion struct as
   found [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/importexportissues/article.php/c123/Explicitly-Linking-to-Classes-in-DLLs.htm)
2. Take a look at the
   file exports and copy explicitly the
   c++ mangle naming convention.

   PFNaddCpp pfnAddCpp = (PFNaddCpp)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "?addCpp@@YAHHH@Z");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inevitably, the access violation on the null pointer is because `GetProcAddress()` returns null on error.

The problem is that C++ names are [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) by the compiler to accommodate a variety of C++ features (namespaces, classes, and overloading, among other things).  So, your function `addCpp()` is not really named `addCpp()` in the resulting library. When you declare the function with `extern "C"`, you give up overloading and the option of putting the function in a namespace, but in return you get a function whose name is not mangled, and which you can call from C code (which doesn't know anything about name mangling.)

One option to get around this is to [export the functions using a **.def** file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh(VS.100).aspx) to rename the exported functions.  There's an article, [Explicitly Linking to Classes in DLLs](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/importexportissues/article.php/c123), that describes what is necessary to do this.

Comment: Is it possible to determine the naming convention from the bindump? See updated question for bindump.

Comment: @Shiftbit:  The name mangling scheme is quite complex; I believe it is an undocumented implementation detail, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I think you might be right. There is a function to demangle the names in something like dbghlp, but it's only a best guess "here is what I think your stacktrace really looks like".

Comment: +1 Thanks The mangle names work... however its not elegant. I enjoyed that article and for larger projects I would consider using that solution. Right now I just want quick access.

Comment: The force_cast technique is seems to be necessary if you want to call the constructor on dynamic class loading. (assuming no constructor helper function)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to just wrap a whole header file in `extern "C"` as follows. Then you don't need to worry about forgetting an `extern "C"` on one of your declarations.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__declspec(dllimport) int addC(int a, int b);
__declspec(dllimport) int addCpp(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif
```

You can still use all of the C++ features that you're used to in the function bodies -- these functions are still C++ functions -- they just have restrictions on the prototypes to make them compatible with C code.